# Subclassing unittest.TestCase, providing keyword args to `super()__init__()` and getting `__init__ got an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python-2.7, inheritance, super, python-unittest

I'm attempting to compose a class hierarchy using unittest.TestCase.  These aren't *strictly* unit-tests I'm running here, I'm trying to instead test a bunch of string parsing functionality that is reliant on a few parameters (customer-name and missing-value for example). The general idea is to simply utilize some of unittest's conveniences and keep things DRY.

```
import unittest
import parsingfunc as i

class CustomerTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    """Base class, most general functionality and test cases"""

    def __init__(self, testname):
        super(CustomerTestCase, self).__init__(testname)

    # helpers

    def mess_with_spaces():
        ...

    def mess_with_case(): 
        ...

    # tests

    def test_case(self, value):
        """
        Test that parsing function produces the same
        value regardless of case of input
        """
        self.assertEqual(self.func(value, missing=self.missing, customer=self.name), 
                         self.func(self.mess_with_case(value), missing=self.missing, customer=self.name)))
        ...

    def test_spaces(self, value):
        """
        Test that parsing function produces the same
        value regardless of spacing present in input
        """
        ...


class AisleValues(CustomerTestCase):
    """Base class for testing aisle values"""

    def __init__(self, testname, customername=None, missing=None):
        super(CustomerTestCase, self).__init__(testname)
        self.name = customername
        self.missing = missing
        self.func = i.aisle_to_num

    ...

class PeacockAisles(AisleValues):
    """Peacock aisle parsing test cases"""

    def __init__(self, testname):
        super(AisleValues, self).__init__(testname, customername='peacock', missing='nan')

    ...
```

And now try to create instances of these classes

```
In [6]: a = i.CustomerTestCase('space_test')

In [7]: a.__dict__
Out[7]: 
{'_cleanups': [],
 '_resultForDoCleanups': None,
 '_testMethodDoc': '\n        Test that parsing function produces the same\n        value regardless of spacing present in input\n        ',
 '_testMethodName': 'test_spaces',
 '_type_equality_funcs': {list: 'assertListEqual',
  dict: 'assertDictEqual',
  set: 'assertSetEqual',
  frozenset: 'assertSetEqual',
  tuple: 'assertTupleEqual',
  unicode: 'assertMultiLineEqual'}}

In [8]: b = i.AisleValues('test_spaces')

In [9]: b.__dict__
Out[9]: 
{'_cleanups': [],
 '_resultForDoCleanups': None,
 '_testMethodDoc': '\n        Test that parsing function produces the same\n        value regardless of spacing present in input\n        ',
 '_testMethodName': 'test_spaces',
 '_type_equality_funcs': {list: 'assertListEqual',
  dict: 'assertDictEqual',
  set: 'assertSetEqual',
  frozenset: 'assertSetEqual',
  tuple: 'assertTupleEqual',
  unicode: 'assertMultiLineEqual'},
 'func': <function integration.aisle_to_num>,
 'missing': None,
 'name': None}

In [10]: b = i.AisleValues('test_spaces', customername='peacock', missing='nan')

In [11]: b.__dict__
Out[12]: 
{'_cleanups': [],
 '_resultForDoCleanups': None,
 '_testMethodDoc': '\n        Test that parsing function produces the same\n        value regardless of spacing present in input\n        ',
 '_testMethodName': 'test_spaces',
 '_type_equality_funcs': {list: 'assertListEqual',
  dict: 'assertDictEqual',
  set: 'assertSetEqual',
  frozenset: 'assertSetEqual',
  tuple: 'assertTupleEqual',
  unicode: 'assertMultiLineEqual'},
 'func': <function integration.aisle_to_num>,
 'missing': 'nan',
 'name': 'peacock'}

In [13]: c = i.PeacockAisles('test_spaces')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-d4bba181b94e> in <module>()
----> 1 c = i.PeacockAisles('test_spaces')

/path/to/python.py in __init__(self, testname)
     89 
     90     def __init__(self, testname):
---> 91         super(AisleValues, self).__init__(testname, customername='peacock', missing='nan')
     92         pprint(self.__dict__)
     93 

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'customername'
```

So what's the deal? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calling `super` correctly. When you name a class in the `super` call, it should be the *current* class, not a base class (unless you really know what you're doing and you want to skip the base class's implementation too, in favor of a "grandparent" class).

Your current code has `AisleValues.__init__` calling `unittest.TestCase.__init__`, bypassing `CustomerTestCase.__init__`. It happens to work because `CustomerTestCase.__init__` doesn't do anything useful (you could delete it with no effect), but that's just luck. When `PeacockAisles.__init__` calls `CustomerTestCase.__init__` (bypassing `AisleValues.__init__`), it fails because the grandparent class doesn't allow all the same arguments as its child.

You want:

```
class AisleValues(CustomerTestCase):
    """Base class for testing aisle values"""

    def __init__(self, testname, customername=None, missing=None):
        super(AisleValues, self).__init__(testname)            # change the class named here
        ...
```

And:

```
class PeacockAisles(AisleValues):
    """Peacock aisle parsing test cases"""

    def __init__(self, testname):
        super(PeacockAisles, self).__init__(testname, customername='peacock', missing='nan')
        ...                                             # and on the previous line
```

Comment: Ahh yes that makes perfect sense, I knew it was something simple.  It works now.  Thanks!